# What is the best way to get numbers from the end of string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string **tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1234567.post-8912345** for example, and I want to get the last numbers "8912345", what is the best way to do this?

```
var str = "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1234567.post-8912345",
    postId = str.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

or

```
var str = "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1234567.post-8912345",
    postId = str.split('-')[2];
```

Comment: If they both work it is somewhat a matter of taste. The first one seems less ad-hoc.

Comment: This is an opinion based question that depends on your specific needs. You could also take a substring from the last index of “-“ to end. There are a hundred ways to skin this cat. Really depends on your needs. Will the format change? Could it be something other than a dash? Then regex all the way. Could it also include characters at some point? Then I guess the split method works better. It’s about future proofing at this point. Neither is objectively better than the other. FWIW, my first instinct was regex when reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first way was better, as it wouldn't matter how many dashes were before the number. You can also use destructuring to remove the `[0]`:

```js
var str = "tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-1234567.post-8912345",
  [postId] = str.match(/\d+$/);

console.log(postId);
```